# Proof a map is multilinear

Tags: multilinear-algebra

Let $n \geqslant 2$. Define the map τ from $\mathbb{K}^n$ × ... × $\mathbb{K}^n$ (where the factor $\mathbb{K}^n$
appears $n$ times) to $\mathbb{K}$ by
$$τ ((x_{1},i)^n
_{i=1}, ...,(x_{n},i)^n
_{i=1}
) := x_{1,1} + x_{2,2} + ... + x_{n,n}.$$

Is the map τ : $\mathbb{K}^n$ × ... × $\mathbb{K}^n$ → $\mathbb{K}$ multilinear?

I have been provided with this solution:

No, τ is not multilinear. For example, if we let $(x_{1,1} + x_{2,2} + ... + x_{n,n}) ∈ \mathbb{K}^n$ have all zero entries except
$x_{1,1} = 1$, fix all columns except the second one $x′_{2}$
is allowed to vary, then the function τ as a
function of $x′_{2}$ is $x′_{2}$→ 1 + $x′_{2,2}$
. This function is not a linear map $\mathbb{K}^n$ → $\mathbb{K}$ (even though it is
affine) so the map τ is not multilinear.

Is there a more systematic approach to the answer?

Comment: What do you mean by systematic?  You need to find an example where one of the conditions for multilinearity fail, that's the process to show that something isn't multilinear.

Comment: So the only way to prove this is by contradiction?

Comment: The main ways to disprove something is via counterexample or contradiction...